# Extracting and splitting the string to create new string which have unique substring

Tags: java, string

Though the Title of question is not clear enough, here is my query:

I have an input String:

```
"this is text <<PATTERN>>some text1 <</PATTERN>><<PATTERN>>some text2 <</PATTERN>><<PATTERN>>some text3 <</PATTERN>> end text"
```

I want to dispaly the output (or new string variable) as follows:

```
String 1= this is text <<PATTERN>>some text1 <</PATTERN>> end text
String 2= this is text <<PATTERN>>some text2 <</PATTERN>> end text
String 3= this is text <<PATTERN>>some text3 <</PATTERN>> end text
String n= this is text <<PATTERN>>some textn <</PATTERN>> end text
```

Basically I want mutiple String having single occurence

```
 <<PATTERN>>some textn <</PATTERN>>.
```

There can be mutiple occurence of `<<PATTERN>>......<</PATTERN>>`  and next set of `<<PATTERN>>......<</PATTERN>>` comes just after the previous.

How I can acheive in JAVA?

Comment: I don't understand your question..

Comment: Use Regex. That's it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun The last line, starting with `Basically` explains what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: @kon Can you share the code how to acheive this?

Comment: @AruniMishra Definitely not. You need to make your own attempt, then come back here and ask questions in-context about any issue with the code that you yourself wrote.

Comment: The question is too broad, because there are many valid answers and may thus be [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Instead, you're encouraged to edit your question by making it more specific. For example, "I want to do X using Y approach but I'm stuck in Z step, or I get an error. What would be the correct way of doing this?" As a reminder, this is a Q&A site, not writing the code for others when they don't even know how to start.

Comment: @kon
I tiried the below code:  

String pattern1 = "<<PATTERN>>";
String pattern2 = "<</PATTERN>>";

String text = "this is text <<PATTERN>>some \n \ttext1 <</PATTERN>><<PATTERN>>some text2 <</PATTERN>><<PATTERN>>some text3 <</PATTERN>> end text";

Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2), Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(text);
  while (m1.find()) {
    System.out.println(m1.group(1));
  }

Using this I can read the string in between <<PATTERN> which i can further used to crearte the Final Strings.

Thanks for suggesting the Regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
    String str = "this is text1<<PATTERN>>some text1 <</PATTERN>><<PATTERN>>some text2 <</PATTERN>><<PATTERN>>some text3 <</PATTERN>> end text";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(((?!<<PATTERN>>).)*)(<<PATTERN>>.*<</PATTERN>>)(.*)");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
    String begin = "";
    String end = "";
    String data = "";
    if(m.find()){
        begin = m.group(1);
        end = m.group(4);
        data = m.group(3);

        //Pattern inner = Pattern.compile("(<<PATTERN>>((?!<<PATTERN>>).)*<</PATTERN>>)");
        Pattern inner = Pattern.compile("(<<[A-Z]{7}>>((?!<<[A-Z]{7}>>).)*<</[A-Z]{7}>>)");
        Matcher mInner = inner.matcher(data);
        while(mInner.find()){
            System.out.println(begin + mInner.group(1) + end);
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("nothing");
    }
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, to make it more generic I gave Pattern.DOTALL in Pattern.compile();
though I doesn't understand the logic fully here, could you please elaborate it little futher?

Comment: Explanation:
I'm using a regular expression grouping to divide the str string into tree portions: begin, data and end, I'm doing it with the first find. Then the second regular expression traverse through the data based on the pattern. You can find and explanation about regular expression grouping here: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)